# Spring boot Stram API large data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using JPA with a Native Query that returns about 13k registers. I thought to use Stream API from Java 8, but the result is not coming.

I Can't paginate because the result will populate a combo box

My repository sends the Stream
I added the @Transactional(readOnly = true) to make it work

```java
@Query(value = "select * from mytable", native = true)
Stream<MyTable> getTableStream()
```

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Stream<MyTable> getTableStream() {
    return repository.getTableStream()
}
```

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/table", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public ResponseEntity<Stream<MyTable>> getMailingClient() {
    Stream<MyTable> body = service.getTableStream();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(body);
}
```

All links and resources I found about stream do not show the implementation of the return JSON with Spring rest API.

My frontend is Angular 6, and nearest I got was one custom object with no result

Comment: `Stream<MailingClient>` and `Stream<MyTable>` are different inside `getMailingClient()`.

Comment: Sorry, my typing mistake. I returning the same object type.

Comment: Surely a TypeAhead field is what you need here rather than a Combo. Example: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 1):

Loading all 13k records into a combo box sounds like a very slow solution. I would recommend implementing a search based on `like` query. Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name like ':name%'")
Stream<MyTable> getTableStream(@Param("name") String name);
```

But if you really want to load all of the records, you can use a `java.util.Collection` or `java.util.List` instead of a stream.

```
Collection<MyTable> getTableStream();
```

Comment: That's the point. With List type, it took about 3 minutes. That's why I'm trying to use Stream. Unfortunately, I can't do a LIKE operation in this case to filter

Comment: @RafaelBandeiraRodrigues The stream will not speed things up. You have to implement a solution, that won't load everything. Try creating a projection with only needed columns. (`select *` takes a lot of time).

Comment: As Alan said, try to write a query that selects fewer things, or re-evaluate your approach. Returning 13K records as JSON to your frontend is unlikely to ever perform well.

Comment: I really understand and share the same thought. But it's an issue from the client. The best way I can do it, is List by letter and group it. But I need to do it without pagination or by the stream so the client can't feel the load delay

Comment: You can use Flex and Mono (Reactive Spring Data repositories) if you are using MongoDB or other databases that Reactive Spring Data provides support for. However, you have to understand that this will execute ~2 minutes instead of ~3. I am sure this is not the desired result. The best thing you can do is to load fewer columns and make sure your database has the column you filter by indexed.

Comment: @AlanSereb, do you have any example of how to do it?